# How to make Clang Complete show the function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, vim, parameters, clang

When auto-completing with Clang Complete, I'd like to make it show the function signature as well.

For instance, if I declare the below function:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b;

    return result;
}
```

When I fire-up Clang Complete, I not only want the function name to pop-up in the auto-completion results, but also it's arguments as well: `add(int a, int b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
set conceallevel=2
set concealcursor=vin
let g:clang_snippets=1
let g:clang_conceal_snippets=1
" The single one that works with clang_complete
let g:clang_snippets_engine='clang_complete'

" Complete options (disable preview scratch window, longest removed to aways
" show menu)
set completeopt=menu,menuone

" Limit popup menu height
set pumheight=20

" SuperTab completion fall-back 
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType='<c-x><c-u><c-p>'
```

Comment: Could you take a quick look on http://stackoverflow.com/q/24803721/2805305 It is very much related to this. Thank you.